# Can anybody help me to understand , Whats are the real life uses of redux in real-life scenario?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Say, I am developing an e-commerce shopping application. Except login/user credential data, what I need to store data into a redux store? I have API & always it need to fetch/insert/update/delete data from database to store Cart items, wish Lists,Order lists etc.
Is it not un-necessary to use redux store as ? Should I not use other global store management system like hooks or global variable ? Can anyone guide me please about actual scenario ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same data, which needs to fetch in different screens(differenet components), so instead of fetch it every time better keep it in redux store. For example you have a list of orders, so this list can be useful in

- Component, which shows list
- Component which shows statistic of orders
- Component which shows and allows to edit particular order

So for all these components you can use one state in store

Yes, you can make a parental component, fetch data in it and then show one of these components depend on routing or some conditions, but then you become attached to this hierarchy, which is not too much convinient and requires to pass the data, which makes code dirty. So redux store can be more convinient